# Test child components based on the results from an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have a parent component that renders a list of child components, but it's based on the result I got from an API call, set the state of the parent component, and render the child components using `this.state`. The problem I have right now is that since `setState` is an async function, by the time the parent component is `mounted` using Enzyme, the `setState` hasn't completed yet and therefore the child components don't exist in the DOM. I just want to know what is the correct way to test the existence of child components in this case?

Any help would be appreciated!

`ParentComponent.js`

```
componentDidMount() {
  someAsyncAPICall().then(status => {
    this.setState({status: status});
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    {this.state.status.map((object, rowIndex) =>
      <ChildComponent key={object.id}
                      ...
      />
    )}
  );
}
```

Mocha unit test for parent

```
import React from 'react';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
...

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
  const status = [{
    ...
  }];
  before(() => {
    fetchMock.get(`${baseURL}/api`, status);
  });

  after(() => {
    fetchMock.reset();
    fetchMock.restore();
  });

  it('contains the correct number of components', (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent />);

    //This is not working - the length of ChildComponent is always 0
    expect(wrapper.find(ChildComponent).length).to.equal(status.length);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the features of mocha.

Is there a way for you to mock the `someAsyncAPICall` function? If you can mock it, then you could do something like what I have [here in the Github gist](https://gist.github.com/newyork-anthonyng/eeab87ab42666b590eea9e865a62de89).

Comment: @AnthonyN Thanks. I used fetch-mock to take care of the api mocking. I think the issue is still within that `setState` hasn't finished when `wrapper` is trying to find `ChildComponent`. That's why the length is always 0

Comment: So you're saying that the code isn't working as expected because `setState` hasn't finished. My original guess was that the code isn't working because `fetchMock` hasn't finished.

Can you add `console.log` statements in your code, like I did [here](https://gist.github.com/newyork-anthonyng/bccf90cdc8ce991fe1a332260ddc9f43).

If your guess is right, then I would expect the logs to go in this order:
`API call finished` -> `hello world` -> `setState finished`

Comment: hmm so I got `hello world` > `API call finished` > `setState finished` @AnthonyN

Comment: Yes, so it seems like your test is finishing before your API has finished. That's why I would try doing what I suggested in the [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/newyork-anthonyng/eeab87ab42666b590eea9e865a62de89) I mentioned earlier.